# Can not sync two S3 buckets using ansible s3_sync module

Tags: ansible

**What do I have:** two S3 buckets named "s3_sync-ansible-test-1" and "s3_sync-ansible-test-2".

Buckets structure:

```
s3_sync-ansible-test-1
|-folder_1
  |-file_1.txt
  |-file_2.txt
|-folder_2
  |-file_2.txt
```

`s3_sync-ansible-test-2` bucket is empty.

**What do I want to do:** sync everything between `s3_sync-ansible-test-1` and `s3_sync-ansible-test-2`.

**What did I tried:**

```
    - name: "Sync S3 buckets"
      register: sync_s3
      s3_sync:
        bucket: s3_sync-ansible-test-2
        file_root: /s3_sync-ansible-test-1

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ sync_s3 }}"
```

Debug output is

```
    "msg": {
        "changed": false, 
        "failed": false, 
        "filelist_actionable": [], 
        "filelist_initial": [], 
        "filelist_local_etag": [], 
        "filelist_s3": [], 
        "filelist_typed": [], 
        "uploads": []
    }
```

At the same time, manual command

```
aws s3 sync s3://s3_sync-ansible-test-1 s3://s3_sync-ansible-test-2
```

works as expected.

I've also tried to change `file_root` to `s3://s3_sync-ansible-test-2` without success.

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the document of s3_sync described:

```
file_root: / required File/directory path for synchronization.This is a local path. This root path is scrubbed from the key name, so subdirectories will remain as keys
```

the **file_root** is a **local path**. which means it can't be a s3 bucket.

if you really want to using this module , you can use [s3fs](https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse) mount s3 bucket to your instance, then using ansible s3_sync to sync it.